# remove unwanted symbols in tagged_sents

Tags: python, nltk

I'm using `nltk` `brown` corpus to get simplified tag set

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown

brown_tags = []

for sent in brown.tagged_sents(categories = 'news', simplify_tags = True):
    brown_tags.extend([tag for (word, tag) in sent])

tag_set = set(brown_tags)
```

then I get

> set(['', 'FW', 'DET', 'WH', "''", 'VBZ', 'VB+PPO', "'", ')', 'ADJ', 'PRO', '*', ',', '.', 'TO', 'NUM', 'NP', ':', 'ADV', '``', 'VD', 'VG', 'VN', 'N', 'P', 'EX', 'V', 'CNJ', 'UH', '(', 'MOD'])

why there are `'', '""', ')',...`?
how can I remove those symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange tags are not mistakes. You can see the full list of tags and their meaning with `nltk.help.brown_tagset()`. The mystery tags represent sentence termination (`.`, the tag for `.`, `?`, `!` etc.), negative words (`*` for `not`, `n't`), etc. So don't throw them out.

Also, the answer you accepted will filter out all double tags, like `VB+PRO` (verb plus pronoun, as in *lemme*, *gimme*). Don't be so quick to throw out information.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove like this,

```
>>> lst = ['', 'FW', 'DET', 'WH', "''", 'VBZ', 'VB+PPO', "'", ')', 'ADJ', 'PRO', '*', ',', '.', 'TO', 'NUM', 'NP', ':', 'ADV', '``', 'VD', 'VG', 'VN', 'N', 'P', 'EX', 'V', 'CNJ', 'UH', '(', 'MOD']    
>>> print ([ i for i in lst if i.isalpha() ])
['FW', 'DET', 'WH', 'VBZ', 'ADJ', 'PRO', 'TO', 'NUM', 'NP', 'ADV', 'VD', 'VG', 'VN', 'N', 'P', 'EX', 'V', 'CNJ', 'UH', 'MOD']
```

Comment: as you suggest, I change my code like this `brown_tags.extend([tag for (word, tag) in sent if tag.isalpha()])`